# Android table layout is not visible

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow, android-relativelayout, layoutparams

I am using this code to show a table dynamically inside a relative layout.

I can see on debug mode that the relative layout and a child of table layout but it is not visible on the screen.

What am I doing wrong?

The code is:

```
RelativeLayout relative = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_relative_layout);

TableLayout.LayoutParams tableLayoutParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams();
tableLayout = new TableLayout(MyActivity.this);
tableLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

TableRow.LayoutParams tableHeaderRowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
tableHeaderRowParams.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
tableHeaderRowParams.weight = 0;
tableHeaderRowParams.span = 2;

TableRow tableHeaderRow = new TableRow(MyActivity.this);
tableHeaderRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

TextView txvHeader = new TextView(MyActivity.this);
txvHeader.setLayoutParams(tableHeaderRowParams);
txvHeader.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
txvHeader.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
txvHeader.setTag(10); txvHeader.setId(10);
txvHeader.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
txvHeader.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, rowTextSize);
txvHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD); txvHeader.setText(“Header”);
tableHeaderRow.addView(txvHeader, tableHeaderRowParams);
tableLayout.addView(tableHeaderRow, tableLayoutParams); 

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpTable = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lpTable.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
lpTable.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
lpTable.topMargin = 9 * space + 6 * rowHeight;

relative.addView(tableLayout, lpTable);
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think you want `tableHeaderRowParams.weight = 1;`, and `MATCH_PARENT` for the `lpTable` width measure.

Comment: @MikeM. You made a miracle!!! Thank you so much! It works!